# AngularJs Ng-Grid : Multiproperty binding with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have Json object:

```
[
   {name: "Moroni", age: 50, dob: 30051998, tob: 1005},
   {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, dob: 30051987, tob: 2205},
   {name: "Jacob", age: 27, dob: 30051956, tob: 0605},
   {name: "Nephi", age: 29, dob: 30051978, tob: 1605},
   {name: "Enos", age: 34, dob: 30051965, tob: 1305}
]
```

Now I want to create one ng-grid, in which there will be one column representing the date and time of birth for each person. Since the data is not properly formatted. So, we want a filter.

```
var gridOptions1 = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [
            { field:"name", displayName: "NAME"},
            { field:"age", displayName: "AGE"},
            { field:"dob+tob", displayName: "Date & Time"}
        ],
        selectedItems: $scope.selected
    };
```

Please help. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFSqLT?p=preview).

Comment: What format do you want the column to be in?  In the end.  Just "dob tob"?

Comment: Hi David, if I give "dob tob", it gives error "Error: Syntax Error: Token 'tob' is an unexpected token at column 16 of the expression [row.entity.dob tob ] starting at [tob ]"

Comment: A custom date filter I want to use. Filter is written in the Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate your initial JSON server data from the data that you are going to push into the ng-grid.

So, before setting your data source for grid2, I would create your view model:

```
$scope.grid2Data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myData.length; i++) {

  $scope.grid2Data.push({

    name: $scope.myData[i].name,
    age: $scope.myData[i].age,
    fullDate: $scope.myData[i].dob.toString() + $scope.myData[i].tob.toString()
  })
}
```

And then configure the columns for grid2 so that you are using the `cellFilter` property:

```
var gridOptions2 = {
        data: 'grid2Data',
        columnDefs: [
            { field:"name", displayName: "Name"},
            { field:"age", displayName: "Age"},
            { field:"fullDate", displayName: "Date & Time", cellFilter:"formatDate:'ddMMyyyyHHmm':'HH:mm MM/dd'"}],
        multiSelect: false,
        selectedItems: $scope.selected
    };
```

Here is a [plunker showing the techniqu](http://plnkr.co/edit/IuYlgk?p=preview)e in action.

This works for all but one date (the one at position 3).  That date doesn't seem to format correctly with your filter.